# Fancy box add button onComplete open current image in new window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to extend fancybox to allow for a new button to open the current image in a new window. I was planning on adding this via the onComplete although I can find any information in the API that explains how to get teh current image from:

```
'onComplete' : function(currentArray, currentIndex, currentOpts){
    alert(currentArray.title);
}
```

Or if you can point me in the direction of some documentation on how I can use the **"currentArray, currentIndex, currentOpts"**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/ANLxC/2/)):

CSS (I used the right arrow icon, but change and/or move this icon whereever you want)

```
#external-link {
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: transparent url('http://i56.tinypic.com/s5wupy.png') -40px -60px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 1103;
}
```

Script

```
$('.popbox').fancybox({
  onComplete: function(currentArray, currentIndex, currentOpts){
    var currentUrl = currentArray[currentIndex].href,
      link = '<a target="_blank" id="external-link" title="Open in a new tab" href="' + currentUrl + '"></a>';
    $('#fancybox-close').before(link);
  }
});
```

Comment: Maybe you can help with my other question working out if the prev/next button should be displayed. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6956035/fancybox-add-left-right-buttons-to-the-title